# Here-API Incidents API prox ApplicationError/InvalidInputData

Tags: here-api

I am trying to make a simple request for traffic incidents within 50 miles of specified co-ordinates with this url

```
https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.3/incidents/json/8/134/86?app_id={{app_id}}&app_code={{app_code}}&prox=51.5074,0.1278,80467&maxresults=10
```

but i am getting this error message:

```
{
    "Details": "Too many selection parameters specified. Please use only one parameter (quadkey or bbox or prox etc.)",
    "AdditionalData": [],
    "type": "ApplicationError",
    "subtype": "InvalidInputData"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/request-constructing.html for constructing your request. You have provided [Z]/[X]/[Y] as well as proximity in your request which is not acceptable. You can provide either one of Quadkey, [Z]/[X]/[Y], Bounding Box, Corridor or Proximity. 
 Your query can be

```
https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.3/incidents.json?app_id={YOUR-APP-ID}&app_code={YOUR-APP-CODE}&prox=51.5074,0.1278,80467&maxresults=10
```

OR

```
https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.3/incidents/json/8/134/86?app_id={YOUR-APP-ID}&app_code={YOUR-APP-CODE}&maxresults=10
```